# Regex to update URLs after a content migration

Tags: php, regex, url, replace, find

I recently moved some old content to a new site and updated some URL structures. I need to do a find-replace on the entire database to update some old links. This would be easy if I knew regex, but I don't so hoping this is easy for the SO guru's.

*Note: This is PHP regex.*

Find:

```
https://api.floodmagazine.com/{number}/{string}/
```

```
Result:
https://api.floodmagazine.com/789/foo-bar/
https://api.floodmagazine.com/12345/foo-bar-1/
```

Replace with:

```
https://floodmagazine.com/$1/$2/
```

```
Result:
https://floodmagazine.com/789/foo-bar/
https://floodmagazine.com/12345/foo-bar-1/
```

It's not as easy as just doing a search for the sub-domain (api.floodmagazine.com) because there are URL's in the DB that need that sub-domain to remain (images for example). So the `/{number/{string}/` part is an important way to find only the URL's that need to be changed.

I just need the regex part, I'm using WP Migrate for the database updating part.

Thanks for the help!

[image: Screenshot for my failed attempt at regex find and replace.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https:\/\/api.floodmagazine.com\/([0-9]+)\/([A-z0-9._+-]+)\/?`
that should work.  On regex101 you have to escape `/` so I kept that here.  That may not be true in your tooling.

You can omit the last `?` if you don’t want the trailing slash to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

This should grab all the URLs you describe :

```
(https://floodmagazine.com)(\/)[0-9]*(\/)[A-z-0-9]*(\/)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I see a pattern error on regex101.com when I try this out. Also, I need the api. in the domain name that I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid URL error du to WordPress inconsistency you can use this PHP code generated with regex101

```php
$re = '/https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?/m';
$str = 'https://api.floodmagazine.com/789/foo-bar/';
$subst = 'https://floodmagazine.com/$2/$3/';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

this regex catch domain, id and post name. Can catch special case like non HTTPS, special char ...
and return the result like expected in your exemple